# Sidebar keeps disappearing when I add content

Tags: html, css

Bear with me as I am fairly new to HTML,

I already have the following HTML:

```
<div class="middle">

    <div class="container">
        <main class="content">
        </main><!-- .content -->
    </div><!-- .container-->
    <aside class="left-sidebar">
        <ul class="nav">
            <li><a href="index.html">HOME</a></li>
            <li><a href="over.html">OVER</a></li>
            <li><a href="reizen.html">REIZEN</a></li>
            <li><a href="afbeeldingen.html">AFBEELDINGEN</a></li>
            <li><a href="boek_nu.html">BOEK NU</a></li>
            <li><a href="forum.html">FORUM</a></li>
        </ul>
    </aside><!-- .left-sidebar -->
    </div><!-- .middle-->
</div><!-- .wrapper -->
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.header {
    height: 60px;
    background: black;
    opacity: 0.7;
    margin-top: 1%;
    position: relative;
    color: white;
    font: helvetica
}
.container {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 10%;
}
.content {
    padding: 0 0 0 270px;
}
/* Left Sidebar -----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
 .left-sidebar {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    width: 10%;
    height;
    150%;
    margin-left: 7%;
    margin-top: 4%;
    opacity: 0.7;
    font-family:"Montserrat", sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: Red;
}
```

Whenever I try to add a big picture in the "content" area, the entire sidebar disappears.
I have some code in CSS which positions the sidebar correctly and I'm fairly sure that is the problem.

My question to you is: What would be the proper CSS code to make the sidebar stay somewhere on the left, with the content area to its right?

Comment: Let's see the CSS! You may have `overflow: hidden;` set on a parent element like `.middle`.

Comment: Right, that might come in handy!

Comment: .wrapper {
 width: 100%;
 margin: 0 auto;
}

.header {
 height: 60px;
 background: black;
 opacity: 0.7;
 margin-top: 1%;
 position: relative;
 color: white;
 font: helvetica
}

.container {
 position: relative;
 width: 100%;
 margin-top: 10%;
}
.content {
 padding: 0 0 0 270px;
}
/* Left Sidebar
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
.left-sidebar {
 position: relative;
 float: left;
 width: 10%;
 height; 150%;
 margin-left: 7%;
 margin-top: 4%;
 opacity: 0.7;
 font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
 font-size: 20px;
 color: Red;
}

Comment: your .container has a width of 100%.  It is pushing it off the page.. reduce it to like 50% and work up to accomodate any paddings, margin, or borders... width takes the width of the parent.  So your container is 100% + your sidebar has 10% width for 110% + margin-left 7% = 117%... cant go over 100% of the browser starts kicking things out to make room for larger items.

Comment: I have reduced it to 50%, but now the sidebar is below the content. Any ideas how to get the content aligned on the right of the sidebar?

Comment: Does the left sidebar have to come after the content in the HTML markup? Also, this may not matter but your CSS refrences a header and the HTML does not have one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a lot of things working against you. Setting `.container` to something like 90% will not work becuase it is not floated. A block level element with a set width will still take up the full width, what happens is the remaining space is filled with a margin. Floating removes that margin but presents other issues you need to be aware of.

If you float `.container` to the right and set it's width to 83% you will achieve what your are looking for. Why 83%? The width of `.left-sidebar` is 10% plus a margin of 7% = 17% total sidebar width. Even after this adjustment I fear it may not be pefect as things like the 10% top margin on `.container` and the 270px of left padding on `.content` and 4% top margin on `.left-sidebar` may not be what you intended.

```css
.wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.header {
    height: 60px;
    background: black;
    opacity: 0.7;
    margin-top: 1%;
    position: relative;
    color: white;
    font: helvetica
}
.container {
    float: right;
    width: 83%;
    margin-top: 10%;
}
.content {
    padding: 0 0 0 270px;
}
.left-sidebar {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    width: 10%;
    height;
    150%;
    margin-left: 7%;
    margin-top: 4%;
    opacity: 0.7;
    font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: Red;
}
```

```html
<div class="middle">
    <div class="container">
        <main class="content">
          <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/400/city">
        </main><!-- .content -->
    </div><!-- .container-->
    <aside class="left-sidebar">
        <ul class="nav">
            <li><a href="index.html">HOME</a></li>
            <li><a href="over.html">OVER</a></li>
            <li><a href="reizen.html">REIZEN</a></li>
            <li><a href="afbeeldingen.html">AFBEELDINGEN</a></li>
            <li><a href="boek_nu.html">BOEK NU</a></li>
            <li><a href="forum.html">FORUM</a></li>
        </ul>
    </aside><!-- .left-sidebar -->
</div><!-- .middle-->
```

Let me take this opportunity to introduce the CSS property [`box-sizing`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing) set with the `border-box` value which allows you to use a different box model.

```css
.example {
   width: 100px;
   padding: 0 10px;
}
```

Normally the total width would be 120px = `10px + 100px + 10px`.

```css
.example {
   box-sizing: border-box;
   width: 100px;
   padding: 0 10px;
}
```

With `box-sizing: border-box` the total width would be 100px = `10px + 90px + 10px` as specified with the width property. If you say something should be XXX width it will be and that amount includes padding, margin etc.

[Should you use `box-sizing: border-box`?](http://www.paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/)

Comment: I finally solved by just deleting all the content HTML and CSS that I had and adding a new div containing just the image that I wanted. Still don't know what was causing the problem the first time, but that doesn't really matter.

Anyway, thank you very much for your support!!

Answer (score 0):

The real problem is in the HTML layout design not the CSS
You should put the left bar (navigation) before the content
something like this: Header, Navigator,Content, Footer

change the width of the container to 90% or less (margin left will take 1% )in the CSS, since navigator is 10%
They should add up to 100%

Comment: Would suggest for a proper answer on SO, to provide a minimal example of the information you are providing to the person asking the question. This person has identified as new to HTML, so it is unlikely that what you are explaining is going to be obvious without some code context.

Comment: Not necessarily, for SEO reasons they may want the navigation to come after the content in the HTML. But I do see what you're getting at, I can see where the HTML could be improved.

Comment: I did what you said, but now the sidebar is on top of the content. It still isn't aligned properly.

Any ideas on how to align the content on the right of the sidebar?

Comment: Still nothing. Even if I change those values by extreme numbers, the picture in the container doesn't even move.

My best guess now would be that it is conflicting with some of the other CSS/HTML code of my website.
Is there an easy way to check this?

Comment: did you specify the width and height in the img tag ??